# Calling javascript function from in objective c using webview methods

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Am trying to call javascript function through objective C

**Steps I have followed:**

In Html Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function init()
{
  alert("Hello Contraceptive_Quiz!");
  setTimeout(function(){destroy()},1000);
}
function destroy()
{
 alert("calling destroy Contraceptive_Quiz!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

In **ObjectiveC.m** file i have used,

In my app bundle wwwfilePath folder exist:

**wwwfilePath structure contains : www/IYG_G8_L05/IYG_G8_L05_Directory/IYGindex1.html**

Here, In this structure contains www/IYG_G8_L05/ Many sub folders

**www/IYG_G8_L05/IYG_G8_L05_Directory1**

**www/IYG_G8_L05/IYG_G8_L05_Directory2**

**www/IYG_G8_L05/IYG_G8_L05_Directory3**

So,I need to load  multiple contents in html page one by one

first time am loading **IYG_G8_L05_Directory1** and then next like ...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IYGindex1" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:wwwfilePath];
NSURL *htmlurl =    [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:htmlurl];
[_contentWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

In webview delegate methods:

** calling javascript functions in objective c**

```
-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"init()"];
[_contentWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
}
```

Here, init( ) method will execute and also executes destroy( ) method because of calling setTimeout( ) function in html page.

My issue is: Once the destroy ( ) method executes, how can i load the next wwwfilepath i.e., IYG_G8_L05_Directory2 it shoud be call in dynamical way.

Let us know how to resolve?

Comment: Any one have an idea about the question?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
For loading content of HTML file dynamically, you could try using AJAX call using XMLHttpRequest().

In below code a url is sent to the loadHTMLURL() function, in which the loaded content is returned.

```
function destroy()
{
   alert("calling destroy Contraceptive_Quiz!");
   document.createElement("body").innerHTML = loadHTMLURL("IYG_G8_L05_Directory1/NEW_HTML.html");
}
function loadHTMLURL(href)
{
   var xmlHTTPObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHTTPObj.open("GET", href, false);
   xmlHTTPObj.send();
   return xmlHTTPObj.responseText;
}
```

I haven't run this code. So carefully check html file url and try into your code.

================================

Solution 2:

Objective-c Code:

```
NSTime *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(_timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSString *function = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"destroy(%@)", @"IYG_G8_L05/IYG_G8_L05_Directory1"];
    NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];
}
```

Javascript Code:

```
function destroy(fileNameWithURL)
    {
       alert("calling destroy Contraceptive_Quiz!");
       document.createElement("body").innerHTML = loadHTMLURL(fileNameWithURL);
    }
```

This above code may helps you.

Comment: Punita, All incrementaions should be done in native it self. so i need to identify when the destroy method executes then it returns a variable. If i received the variable in iOS then i can call the increment functionality to call the further directory i.e.,IYG_G8_L05_Directory2

Comment: Hey @JoshKethepalli, Not understand your question, What do you want? Let me clear my understanding, You want to execute some initial HTML page in UIWebview, then in objective-c (native) you want to start counter (incrementations), and after reach come interval (counter) you want call JS destroy method to load next directory's HTML page content. Is this right?

Comment: Yes,It all should be done in dynmically with out user interaction, when ever time interval reached.. means.. destroy method will call and immediately load next activity

Comment: Hey @JoshKethepalli see my updated answer with 'Solution 2'. In this you have NSTimer for count time interval in Objective-c native code. and you can send file name with url into javascript method for loading particular html file's content.

Comment: Timer functionality is in Javascript. I have used setTimeout